# Why does `ul` have ARIA role `menu` but `menuitem` is forbidden for `li`?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

Just covered out some strage specs regarding [ARIA roles](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles). **Why does `ul` have ARIA role `menu` but `menuitem` is forbidden for `li`?**

I would like to describe a navigation bar using `ul`, `li` and HTML5's `nav` element in combination with the ARIA roles `navigation`, `menu` and `menuitem`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><title>ARIA role bug?</title></head>
  <body>
    <nav role="navigation">
      <ul role="menu">
        <li role="menuitem"><a href="http://example.com/">example.com</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

[W3's HTML5 validator](http://validator.w3.org/) nag me here:

> Bad value menuitem for attribute role on element li.

Comment: I have answered below, but would also say that if the navigation consists of just links on on a web page and does not have the interaction behaviour associated with a menu and menu items then the ARIA roles should not be used.Refer to the menu design pattern for more details http://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria-practices/#menu

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Jukka is [incorrect here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16754008/1361227). The [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/nu/) does not check against the WHATWG LS, instead it checks against the [W3C HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#wai-aria). The W3C HTML spec is the authoritative source for conformance checking requirements for the W3C Validator.

In regards to `menuitem` not being allowed as per the HTML spec, I believe this is a bug. And as such I have [filed a bug](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=22164). It is now in my bug queue to be resolved.

I have filed a bug against the [W3C validator](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=22165) and [wai-aria in HTML](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=22166) doc as well.
Until such times the validator is fixed, I suggest you use the roles as per the WAI-ARIA spec and ignore the validator.

addendum:

I looked back at history of ARIA integration into HTML could not find any reason why `menuitem` was not allowed, so believe it was an oversight. I fixed and resolved the bug I referenced above.

Comment: Do we really need to specify role="menuitem" here on a <li> element, beyond <ul role="menu">? It is quite verbose and seems redundant of the existing <li> semantic.

Comment: Also I see the issue as: "Fixed and pushed to the validator" on 2013-06-26. Though it still doesn't validate as of today? Thanks

Comment: Good to see this has been reported and fixed.

Answer (score 3):

The following HTML markup is in the ARIA spec itself (the one you linked), and clearly shows a `LI` (nested, even) being used as a menuitem. Im guessing the particular markup you are using is forcing it to non-conform but thats just a hunch.

```
<ul role="menubar">

 <!-- Rule 2A: "File" label via aria-labelledby -->
  <li role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true" aria-labelledby="fileLabel"><span id="fileLabel">File</span>
    <ul role="menu">

      <!-- Rule 2C: "New" label via Namefrom:contents -->
      <li role="menuitem">New</li>
      <li role="menuitem">Open…</li>
      …
    </ul>
  </li>
  …
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't put role="menuitem" on an ***li element*** when it contains an ***a element*** since a menuitem widget cannot contain any intereactive elements (e.g links).

Take a look at the [aria-practices](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#menu) examples for menu.

```
<li role="none">
  <a role="menuitem">my menuitem here</a>
</li>
```

or

```
<li role="menuitem">my menuitem here</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The W3C validator, when applying HTML5 rules, actually checks against (some version of) the WHATWG “Living HTML standard”, which currently says, in clause 3.2.7 [WAI-ARIA](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#wai-aria), about “li element whose parent is an ol or ul element” the following: “Role must be either listitem, menuitemcheckbox, menuitemradio, option, tab, or treeitem”.

This corresponds to the rules in the “Using WAI-ARIA in HTML” W3C draft, in 2.9 [Recommendations Table](http://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#recommendations-table).

Comment: They have removed it but why?! This is really stupid by the spec writers due to break of spec itself

Comment: If you've noticed `Passed, 1 warning(s)`, the warning's because this is a **draft** specification, as stated:

`Using experimental feature: HTML5 Conformance Checker.`

Comment: In conformance checker parlance: error= MUST level requirement in the HTML spec. Warning = SHOULD level requirement

Answer (score 0):

I was using a similar DOM and changing an `li` submenu's role to [presentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#presentation) made the the page validate. Although perhaps semantically incorrect, in my situation it is inconsequential.

Comment: presentation probably makes it ignored and won't be read out by some readers

Comment: the answer is correct, but you need to set `li` role to `presentation` or `none`  and the `a` role to `menuitem`. Left that out.